# JSON.parse a string with an escape

Tags: javascript, json

Currently I am attempting to parse a long object with JSON.Parse
The object contains a lot of data but specifically this is causing an issue:

```
OG\'S RIDES
```

I get this data with an Ajas call.
I convert the data with JSON.stringify

```
const jsonOrders = JSON.stringify(orders).replace(/[\/\(\)\']/g, "\\$&");
```

To use this data in an Adobe CEP Panel I pass the data like so:

```
csiRun.evalScript(`setupSwitchBlade('${jsonOrders}', '${layoutFile}', '${orderDate}', '${productTag}', 1)`);
```

The object is a large string with multiple items so it would be something like (just an example not valid viewed from console):

```
{id: 113592, order_number: "204736", internal_order: "204736-0", order_date: "11-15-2021", custom1: "OG\'S RIDES"}
```

The entire object is being passed as a string and then I have to parse it.  I parse it like so:

```
var orderParsed = JSON.parse(orders);
```

This causes the error I get JSON.Parse error.
I tracked down the issue to this string also indicated above:

```
OG\'S RIDES
```

As you can see the cause of the issue is being escaped but I still get the error.
Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: What system generates the JSON?

Comment: The example text you provided is not valid JSON.  And FYI, JSON parse errors usually provide more details to the error.  Something like `{id: 113592}` might produce something like `Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1`  Also `JSON.parse` uses a lowercase `p`, in case that's it.

Comment: `JSON.parse` has no problems with the escaped quote.

Comment: I pull from a mysql database with ajax.  I then pass it into adobe cep panel by creating it into JSON.stringify.  @Bergi

Comment: Yes I pointed out "something like this" The data is pulled from a database and then I stringify it to pass into an Adobe CEP Panel @Wyck

Comment: @FabricioG What do you mean by "*pass it into adobe cep panel*", can you show the code that does that? As well the as the code that receives the JSON string? Any `JSON.stringify` output should be `JSON.parse`able.

Comment: Updated, thank you! @Bergi

Comment: `.replace(/[\/\(\)\']/g, "\\$&");` is weird, why are you replacing slashes and parenthesis? What you *should* have escaped are backslashes (and the apostrophes that make up your string delimiters in ``csiRun.evalScript(`setupSwitchBlade('${jsonOrders}')`)``).

Comment: There is a simpler options though: pass an object literal to `setupSwitchBlade`! The JSON is a valid JS expression, ``csiRun.evalScript(`setupSwitchBlade(${JSON.stringify(orders)}, '…')`)`` (notice the lack of apostrophes). If you do need to pass the JSON as a string, don't do the escaping yourself, use `JSON.stringify`: ``csiRun.evalScript(`setupSwitchBlade(${JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(orders))}, '…')`)`` (which will generate a double-quoted string, not one with apostrophes).

Comment: @Bergi trying those two methods.

Comment: It would be amazing if you could post the exact contents of `orders` in your question.  Clearly it's not JSON because it fails to parse as JSON, but what it **does** contain, would be very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that JSON format Expecting 'STRING'!

```
{id: 113592, order_nu
-^
```

So surround properties with double quotes `"`

```js
{"id": 113592, "order_number":...}
```

with a readable format:

```js
const json = `{
  "id": 113592,
  "order_number": "204736",
  "internal_order": "204736-0",
  "order_date": "11-15-2021",
  "custom1": "OG'S RIDES"
}`
console.log(JSON.parse(json))
//JAVASCRIPT Object:
//{ id: 113592, order_number: "204736", internal_order: "204736-0", order_date: "11-15-2021", custom1: "OG'S RIDES" }
```

Comment: I updated with more code.  The data is stringified before it's passed to another area.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your properties must be quoted for it to be valid JSON.  Don't confuse JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) with JavaScript.  :)

```js
input = `{"id": 113592, "order_number": "204736", "internal_order": "204736-0", "order_date": "11-15-2021", "custom1": "OG\'S RIDES"}`
result = JSON.parse(input)
console.dir(result);
```

Comment: I updated the code to better reflect the issue.  The object I put was just an example from the console.log

Answer (score -1):

The object that you get is not a valid stringified object.
So To fix your issue, you have to stringify the object first and parse it again.

```js
const object = JSON.stringify({id: 113592, order_number: "204736", internal_order: "204736-0", order_date: "11-15-2021", custom1: "OG\'S RIDES"});

// `{"id":113592,"order_number":"204736","internal_order":"204736-0","order_date":"11-15-2021","custom1":"OG'S RIDES"}`

const data = JSON.parse(object);

// {id: 113592, order_number: '204736', internal_order: '204736-0', order_date: '11-15-2021', custom1: "OG'S RIDES"}
```